# How do I auto run extension install command on Heroku when provisioning DB using pipelines?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, postgis, geodjango, heroku-postgres

I'm using the Heroku Pipelines feature to auto create a review app whenever I create a new PR in github. This will provision a new DB for you and migrate all your database schema. When migrating this schema I receive this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type'
```

I want to use PostGIS which means I need to run `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` 
on the db after it's automatically provisioned. My hunch is that I'm getting this error because the extension isn't installed yet by the time it runs `python manage.py migrate`. How would I run this in an automated way when it's building my review app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a kludge since review apps don't support it natively yet but you could teach your `postdeploy` script a new trick. Something like this:

> "postdeploy": "echo 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;' | psql $DATABASE_URL && --run your migrations here--"

This will pipe in the extension creation prior to running your migrations which should solve the troubles you're seeing.